# what are the ports I should open on linux for wso2-emm

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I read this doc
[EMM110/Default+Ports+of+WSO2+Products](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Default+Ports+of+WSO2+Products)

I cange the ports
9443 to 9766 
9763  to 9764
I opened
ports form 9764 -> 9770

I changed these ports to in carbon.xml

```
<JMX>
        <!--The port RMI registry is exposed-->
        <RMIRegistryPort>9768</RMIRegistryPort>
        <!--The port RMI server should be exposed-->
        <RMIServerPort>9770</RMIServerPort>
    </JMX>
```

what other config I should do ?

Comment: How did you changed the port 9443 to 9766?

Comment: emm\repository\conf\tomcat\catalina-server.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the ports in axis2 config and tomcat config. All config files are in the `\repository\conf\`.

There may be some other ports! I recommend you to check all the used ports by `$netstat -nltp` and monitor the used ports after your changes to get sure that you have changed all ports you wanted and all of them are working properly.